# rails, nginx server says no version information available for libxslt.so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, capistrano, ubuntu-12.04

When I try to start nginx, this is what happens. Not sure what i need to do. Apache is off.

```
sudo nginx 
nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxslt.so.1: no version information available (required by nginx)
nginx: /usr/local/lib/libxslt.so.1: no version information available (required by nginx)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the real issue is "Address already in use".  You probably already have Apache or another instance of Nginx bound to port 80.  You can use `lsof -i tcp:80` to check.

The linker warning is just that: a warning.  Most likely when you compiled Nginx, it linked against a different version of libxslt (perhaps under /usr/lib), but at runtime, it's finding the version under /usr/local/lib.  In any case, it shouldn't prevent Nginx from running.

Comment: Thanks! that makes a lot of sense

Comment: Is there any way to find out if the nginx server is running?

Comment: Yes, you can either grep it from the list of processes, e.g. "ps aux | grep nginx", or you can use "lsof" as I mentioned in the answer.  Using "lsof" is the better method, since it might not be Nginx bound to port 80.